# Sending custom SNS notifications to only selected endpoints- using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Let say I have 100 people who subscribed to a topic called :"remeinde_me_my_appointment" and I have lambda function that gives me a list of 5 people with their endpoints who should be reminded about their appointments tomorrow.

Now my question is, how does the communication between lambda and SNS should work?

All I want to do is to send 5 messages to 5 people who signed up to receive notifications and well I've magically got all their endpoints.

Am I sending them back to the topic again?!  what do I do form here I'm confused? It looks like I've defined my own topic and subscription already but what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good use-case for subscribing to an Amazon SNS topic.

When a message is sent to an SNS topic, **all recipients receive the message**. You can also use [Amazon SNS Message Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) to limit which subscribers receive a message, based on a message attribute.

However, based on your use-case, this is **not a good way to send your messages**. Your use-case would probably be better handled by **sending individual messages to each person** with customized information about their appointment, such as:

`Dear Joe, this is a reminder of your appointment with Dr Smith at 10am tomorrow.`

So, instead of sending a message to a Topic, use the Amazon SNS [`publish()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) command with an Endpoint ARN:

```
sns.publish(TargetArn=user_endpoint_arn, Message=msg)
```

> To use the Publish action for sending a message to a mobile endpoint, such as an app on a Kindle device or mobile phone, you must specify the EndpointArn for the TargetArn parameter. The EndpointArn is returned when making a call with the CreatePlatformEndpoint action.

This is good for sending a message to a mobile application.

If, instead, you are **merely sending an SMS message**, then you can publish directly to the mobile number:

```
sns.publish(PhoneNumber='+16025551234', Message=msg)
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @John - suppose if user device token changes, then endpoint arn would also change, then subscription arn would also change right ? so I think sending message directly to user is good instead of adding all users to topic as subscriptions ? Correct me if I am wrong